# How can I know the real number of physical cores in a CPU?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, 64-bit, logical-processor

As of recently, I have been studying for my comptia A+ certificate and I was going over task manager for the core 2 material I've been reading. I decided to open up my task manager and check out my CPU. You may laugh at the CPU I'm currently using but AMD has bam boozled me.

When I first bought my CPU I thought I was getting 4 physical cores, turns out that I only have 2 and 4 logical cores. For the next time that I buy a new and better CPU, how can I know how many physical cores I'm really getting?

Comment: what cpu did you get?

Comment: https://www.cpubenchmark.net will allow you to search by CPU, nd in addition to telling you the number of cores nd breakdown, it also gives you a number which is a very handy rough-and-ready comparison of relative CPU performance (higher numbers are better).  If you are buying an Intel CPU, you can look at its specifications at ark.intel.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel has used hyperthreading on many processors for some time to provide logical cores. Some of AMDs latest Ryzen chips are now using Simultaneous Multi Threading as well to provide logical processors.

To find how many physical and logical cores a CPU has before purchasing, look up the CPU model in the Wikipedia page for that generation of processor. For chips using logical cores, the true number of cores is listed in the table, with the total logical cores in parenthesis. 4(4) for example denotes 4 physical cores, while 2(4) denotes 4 logical cores running on 2 physical cores.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_microprocessors

AMD currently has 4 consumer product lines:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_accelerated_processing_units
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Ryzen_microprocessors
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlon_X4
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_FX_microprocessors

Answer (score 2):

You can look up the processor specifications on the manufacturer's official site:

- [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/products/specifications/processors)
- [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html#@Processors)

Physical cores are listed in the spec sheets as "# of cores", logical ones as "# of threads".

Comment: Good answer!!!!